# C - realloc a structs member variable of type pointer in a function. Valgrind reports "Invalid read/write of size 1"

Tags: c, function, struct, valgrind, realloc

My question pertains to running [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) against the following unit test below. The unit test passes when running `make clean all check`, however when running [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on the produced executable I get errors of the form:

```
Running suite(s): File System
==18845== Invalid read of size 1
==18845==    at 0x4C2B8C4: strcat (vg_replace_strmem.c:303)
==18845==    by 0x4E35E5F: filename_app (filename.c:196)
==18845==    by 0x401871: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:157)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
==18845==  Address 0x6154900 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==18845==    at 0x4C2AC9B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==18845==    by 0x4E35E0B: filename_app (filename.c:187)
==18845==    by 0x401871: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:157)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
==18845==  Block was alloc'd at
==18845==    at 0x4C28D06: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==18845==    by 0x52CC899: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==18845==    by 0x4E35A31: filename_create (filename.c:44)
==18845==    by 0x401815: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:153)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
...
=18845== Invalid write of size 1
==18845==    at 0x4C2B8FF: strcat (vg_replace_strmem.c:303)
==18845==    by 0x4E35E5F: filename_app (filename.c:196)
==18845==    by 0x401871: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:157)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
==18845==  Address 0x6154908 is 3 bytes after a block of size 5 free'd
==18845==    at 0x4C2AC9B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==18845==    by 0x4E35E0B: filename_app (filename.c:187)
==18845==    by 0x401871: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:157)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
==18845==  Block was alloc'd at
==18845==    at 0x4C28D06: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==18845==    by 0x52CC899: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==18845==    by 0x4E35A31: filename_create (filename.c:44)
==18845==    by 0x401815: test_filename_app (check_file_system.c:153)
==18845==    by 0x503D78A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x503DB7C: srunner_run (in /usr/lib64/libcheck.so.0.0.0)
==18845==    by 0x401ACE: main (check_file_system.c:196)
...
100%: Checks: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0
==18845== 
==18845== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18845==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18845==   total heap usage: 222 allocs, 223 frees, 62,433 bytes allocated
==18845== 
==18845== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18845== 
==18845== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18845== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My unit test being of the form:

```
START_TEST(test_filename_app)
{
  filename_t file;

  // Just to check for crashes. No actual unit test.
  filename_app(NULL, "frog");

  file = filename_create("frog");

  filename_app(&file, NULL);
  ck_assert_str_eq("frog", file.name);
  filename_app(&file, ".ext");
  ck_assert_str_eq("frog.ext", file.name);

  filename_free(&file);
}
END_TEST
```

If I comment out `filename_app(&file, ".ext");` and its associated test the [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) erros go away. The function being tested, which passes in "all forms" is:

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
} filename_t;

void filename_app(filename_t *name, const char *app)
{
  void *tmp = NULL;

  if (name == NULL || name->name == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  if (app == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  size_t name_bytes_cnt = strlen(name->name);
  size_t app_bytes_cnt = strlen(app);
  size_t new_bytes_cnt = name_bytes_cnt + app_bytes_cnt + sizeof(char);

  errno = 0;
  tmp = realloc((void *)name->name, new_bytes_cnt);
  if (errno == ENOMEM || tmp == NULL) {
    free(tmp);
    return;
  }
  if (tmp != name->name) {
    free(tmp);
  }

  strcat(name->name, app);
}
```

What am I doing wrong to get one extra free and the Invalid read/write?

Comment: This is aside from your question, but you have an off by one error in your code.  You need to add `+1` to your `new_bytes_cnt` in the realloc call to account for the `\0` that the `strcat` will *automatically* tack onto the end of the string.

Comment: Some of the logic in `filename_app` doesn't make sense.  After the call to `realloc`, it checks `errno` regardless of whether there's a failure.  I think it's only guaranteed to be set if `realloc` returns `NULL`.  Then it compares `tmp` to `name->name`, but if it's not equal, it frees it, then goes ahead and tries to copy `app` to the old pointer, which may not hold enough space for it.  I suggest sitting down and *thinking* about what you want it to do.

Comment: What is the benefit of the structure that contains a single pointer, compared to just using `char *`?  I suppose it gives a name to the type, but that seems a marginal benefit.

Comment: `strlen` returns the actual number of characters up to (but *not including*) the null.  If you use strlen to figure out a string's length, you must always +1 the allocation (or with a wchar, +2 or more, depending on what kind of characters they are)

Comment: @MatthewHoggan First check if you got `NULL` from `realloc`, only then check what `errno` got set to, if you need to.

Comment: I think you're missing my main point.  Why are you calling `realloc` in the first place?  You are discarding the result, in all cases.  Clearly it isn't right.  If a new pointer is returned, you need to *save* the new pointer, and use the *new* pointer in your call to `strcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need the struct, the checks you make could be more straightforward:

```
typedef struct { char *name; } filename_t;

void filename_app(filename_t *name, const char *app)
{
  if (!app || !name || !name->name ) return;

  size_t name_bytes_cnt = strlen(name->name), 
          app_bytes_cnt = strlen(app),
          new_bytes_cnt = name_bytes_cnt + app_bytes_cnt + sizeof(char);

  void* tmp = realloc((void *)name->name, new_bytes_cnt);
```

This:

```
if (tmp != name->name) {
    free(tmp);
  }

  strcat(name->name, app);
}
```

doesn't make sense. `tmp` will be equal to `name->name` if the `realloc` succeeded without moving, but if it succeeded *with* moving, then `strcat`ing to `name->name` is undefined (`name->name` would then be `free`d memory (`free`d by `realloc`)).

Comment: I missread the manpages, reading: `The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, ... and may be different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails. ..." as it would be NULL if it fails but can be different from ptr. However, this doesn't resolve the issue because tmp == ptr in my case. I just added an assert and it passes every run.
`

Comment: That's because you're working with short strings so a realloc without moving is very likely. If the strings got longer, the assert would start breaking.

Comment: working on fixing up code. Ill get back if the valgrind errors continue. If they go away ill mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
tmp = realloc((void *)name->name, new_bytes_cnt);
if (errno == ENOMEM || tmp == NULL) {
    free(tmp);
    return;
 }
 if (tmp != name->name) {
    free(tmp);
 }
```

If `realloc()` succeeds and has actually performed a resize, then `tmp != name->name` will be true.    Your code then releases the newly allocated block, not the block you had before resizing.

If `realloc()` fails, `tmp` will be `NULL`, so there is no need to pass it to `free()`.

Also, not all implementations set `errno` to be `ENOMEM` if `realloc()` fails (that's a POSIX thing, not a C standard thing).    And those which do don't always change `errno` if `realloc()` succeeds - so the value of `errno` being tested might be a result of some other (previously executed in your program) code, unrelated to your function.

You haven't stated what the caller of your function expects to happen either.   If `realloc()` fails, does the caller expect the old value to be kept or not?

Comment: Hince the ||. If ENOMEM == errno and tmp != NULL then perhaps it should be free'd? I would assume the pointer returned at that point would be safe to be free'd.

Comment: If `errno == ENOMEM` due to something preceding the latest `realloc()` call, then you're (again) releasing the newly allocated block if `realloc()` has successfully reallocated.   Your logic is backward.